# Как можно безболезненно подключить bootstap к Yii проекту?

Tags: php, yii, bootstrap

Сейчас разрабатываем один проект на yii (работает 2 программиста я и мой коллега). И вот возник такой вопрос - Как можно безболезненно подключить bootstap к проекту, если проект уже сделан процентов на 30-40? Что посоветуете? Как лучше поступить подключать расширение yii-bootstap или голый bootstrap?

Я думаю, что может просто скачать bootstrap и подключить его, а не как по-правильному через extensions... Очень хочу услышать Ваше мнение...

Comment: Бутстрап - это просто css (и немного опционального js/шрифтов). Сам по себе он не может неправильно подключен. Yii-bootstrap - это, главным образом, набор виджетов для Yii. Вопрос не в том, "как правильно подключить" (и, вообще-то, в эпоху композера расширения уже совсем не комильфо), а нужен ли этот пак виджетов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лично я в Yii проектах использую расширение yii-bootstrap, и вам советую. Если использовать голый бутстрап то как минимум придется со стилистикой виджетов помучатся.